# Layout icon auto generated activity

Tags: java, android

I am currently using android studio 2.3.3 with Kotlin and I dont know why these icon are automatically generated (you can see the picture below). Normally I have only one icon. The four icons are exactly the same when I click on it
[image]

Comment: Try `Build - Clean Project` and `Build - Rebuild`.